# How to show a visual indicator when mute all sounds is enabled

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, volume-control, buttons, mute

On the Galaxy S9 (and I presume later versions, though I don't know for sure) there is a "mute all sounds" setting that can be toggled by pressing the power and volume up buttons simultaneously. While this can be quite convenient, it's also very easy to either forget to disable it, or to enable it accidentally in the first place, and then you miss important alarms and notifications until you notice.

Is there any way to get a visual indication when mute all sounds is enabled, such as a status bar icon or making the perimeter glow a certain color?

Yes, I know that you can *check* whether mute all sounds is enabled by pressing either volume up or volume down, which will show a greyed out volume bar with a caption that says "Mute all sounds is turned on" if it's enabled, but I'm looking for some kind of visual indication that alerts you that it's enabled when you're not actively thinking to check.

Comment: Maybe this app helps https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=muter.muter// or https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dc7.SilentModeToggle

Comment: @beeshyams That app doesn't seem to have any connection to the mute all sounds feature. "Mute all sounds" isn't a descriptive phrase that I'm using to refer to putting the phone in vibrate or DND mode, it's the actual name of the feature, and it's different than muting from the volume control.

Comment: Thanks. I thought otherwise (descriptive phrase) and therefore suggested those apps that can substitute the function of vol and power keys

Comment: On the Galaxy 23 Ultra, enabling Mute All Sounds does at least change the sound icon on the Quick Panel from loudspeaker-with-radiating-waves to greyed-out-loudspeaker-with-prohibition-symbol (). This doesn't meet the OP's request, however, because you have to drag down to see the Quick Panel.

In contrast, the similar Do Not Disturb feature does not change the sound icon on the Quick Panel, but does put an indicator icon (in the form of the do-not-enter symbol ⛔) on the status bar.

Comment: What everyone would want, I think, is that both features change the appearance of the sound icon on the Quick Panel and that both features put the corresponding notification icon on the status bar.